# JBoss Changing sessionId JSF

Tags: jsf, jboss, sessionid

Hi I have problem with the session Id being changed in Jboss 7, this dosen't happen in Jboss 6. Is there a setting that I am missing. If anyone has any ideas pls share it... BTW Jboss 7 seems to be really fast when compared to Jboss 6.

Jboss 6 - as the application is accessed for the first time

```
09:52:12,409 INFO  [com.em.emt.util.LoginFilter] User not logged-in redirecting to login.jsf...
09:52:12,409 INFO  [com.em.emt.util.LoginFilter] Client IP:127.0.0.1,Date:Thu Jul 14 09:52:12 EDT 2011
09:52:12,409 INFO  [STDOUT] _ sessionId:1B42D03EEA3AD284F205BDB746BCC32B
09:52:12,425 INFO  [STDOUT] _ sessionId:1B42D03EEA3AD284F205BDB746BCC32B
09:52:12,440 INFO  [com.em.emt.util.LoginFilter] User not logged-in redirecting to login.jsf...
09:52:12,440 INFO  [com.em.emt.util.LoginFilter] Client IP:127.0.0.1,Date:Thu Jul 14 09:52:12 EDT 2011
09:52:12,456 INFO  [STDOUT] _ sessionId:1B42D03EEA3AD284F205BDB746BCC32B
```

Jboss 7 - notice how the sessionId is changing that causing to redirect the user to login page.

10:07:23,671 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) ***_*** *sessionId:QB6w47mweQ2LcF9jYm4+FCDj*
10:07:24,124 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) **_*null
10:07:30,764 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) _*___** *sessionId:QB6w47mweQ2LcF9jYm4+FCDj*
10:07:49,374 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) ***_*** *sessionId:QB6w47mweQ2LcF9jYm4+FCDj*
10:07:50,421 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) ***_*** *sessionId:O1vHiFFJY48uQfNBud8xeem4*
10:07:50,437 INFO  [stdout] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) ***_*** *sessionId:x8HVCelSqYCmsf0y0me1Hbng*